# Eclipse-PDT - Define own shortcut with action

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

is there a way to define own shortcut with specific action in Eclipse PDT? For example, in Notepad++, you can define that **CTRL+S** will save the file and run the console with specific command. Example:
You save the PHP file with **CTRL+S** command and after saving the file, the console will run this file in php.exe and it will output possible PHP errors in console.

Thank you.

Comment: You can [execute an Ant script when a project file or folder is modified, deleted or added](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-93_project_builder.htm). You can also run scripts (JavaScript, etc.) with [Eclipse EASE](https://www.eclipse.org/ease/).

Comment: Hi, thank you for the info, is there any documentation describing how to access internal commands in Eclipse through the scripting. My interest is just 1) save the file and 2) run the file in php.exe (defined for run command) with CTRL+S

Comment: For scripting via Eclipse EASE I recommend [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K9ERWs2ixZY).